# Multiline Legend Label with Pie Chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to have multiline labels with a pie chart on ChartJS. I've read on multiple questions that using an array of strings should get the job done, yet I'm not seeing it. My code is as follows:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-inversiones");

window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: pieInversiones,
    options: {
        legend: {
            position: 'left',
            onClick: function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            },
            labels: {
                fontColor: "#15467D",
                fontFamily: "Neo Sans Std",
                fontSize: 10
            }
        },
        animation: {
            animateRotate: getParameterByName("action") == "print" ? false : true
        },
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                color: '#15467D',
                anchor: "end",
                align: "end",
                formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                    return value + "%";
                }
            }
        }
    },
});
```

With the data object having two properties, dataset (data with the background color) and labels, which is just an array of arrays, each having 1+ strings in it.

Most questions I see ask about bar charts, how would I go about achieving this on a pie one?

Here's an example of the code I'm using https://jsfiddle.net/04zcy2hu/

Comment: Can you please provide js fiddle with the data rendering on it.

Comment: @Pankaj updated with example fiddle.